# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 Issues Seeing Install on Desktop

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a small PC I built,

Specs:

```
 ECS H87H3-TI thin-mini ITX motherboard
 i3 4330 CPU 
 8gb of RAM
 120gb SSD.
```

Whenever I try to install Ubuntu, whether through flash storage or DVD, I get the same result: it boots to the regular options to either install, run off USB, check for disk errors, etc., I select 'install', the desktop shows up, but it's completely empty...

I can move the mouse and I have the regular options in the top right corner on the grey bar, but I have nothing else on the screen apart from the wallpaper and if I move the mouse past the left or bottom edge of the screen, it continues on as if the desktop extends past what I can actually see. I tried to adjust the screen settings but there's nothing that I could find to let me adjust to have everything appear on one screen. I also tried multiple different monitors and I get the same results.

I searched on the net for an answer but I found nothing related to my issue. There are a lot of posts of people getting just black screens, but I have the desktop, but no installation window.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Please double check the md5sum of the ISO you downloaded and insure that it matches. If not, download it again, insuring that you have a good copy by checking the md5sum prior to creating your installation media. A long list of md5sums and how to check them is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

**2)** You also may wish to attempt installation from a minimal CD which uses a **text** based installer and will download the packages at install time. Instructions, links and md5sums for the minimal cd are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr to a desktop from a DVD that had previously been used to successfully install to my laptop, i.e. getting past the option to install, seeing the desktop with system icon in top right hand of screen, but no install screen.

For me, the solution was to use that posted for the black/purple screen issue, by setting a check against nomodeset, as per step 2 in the following post:
[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

1) load install disc and reboot
2) when purple screen shows up - hold down the down arrow
3) Hit F6
4) Scroll down to nomodeset and hit enter
5) hit escape 
6) select Install Ubuntu

I was then able to proceed to install, and after a few scary looking screens arrived at the desktop with an install screen.
The above post gives screen shots and other options too.